# How to know when a WPF Window has snapped/unsnapped in Windows?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, windows-10, window, snapping

Im using a WPF Window in the `WindowsStyle='none'`;

With this I create my own custom window by giving the `'root' grid` (the highest in the XAML-tree) a `Margin of 20px` and a `DropShadow`. The window itself is transparant, the grid has a white background.

When I set the `WindowsStyle.Maximized`, I remove the extra `Margin` and the `DropShadow` . When I set `WindowsStyle.Normal` I add the extra `Margin` and the `DropShadow` again.

But when I snap my WPF window in Windows 10 to a corner or side of my screen. It snaps but I dont get an `Window.StateChanged` event.

My question is: Is there anyway to figure out when my Window has snapped in Windows and when it Unsnapped?

Comment: The Windows "aero snap" feature that is built into the OS does not expose any snap/unsnap events that you can use in WPF or any Win32 apps.  However, the result of these snaps are a window resize.  So you might be better off listening to the `Window.SizeChanged` event instead of `Window.StateChanged` for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I think that would do it because I know code wise when the user resizes the window by pulling on the sides of the window...